# Android show spinner in toolbar when user navigates to a particular fragment(3rd tab fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three tabs like Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 and i have viewpager in MainFragment to display these three tabs. How can i display a spinner in toolbar only when user navigates to Tab3.

Comment: take a customview with spinner on toolbar,for tab1 and tab2 hide it for tab3 show it

Answer (score 0):

Insert spinner in toolbar custom view, implement ViewPager callbacks to receive current pager position and make some logic:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    super.onPageSelected(position);
    if (position == 0 || position == 1)
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide spinner
    else if (position == 2)
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show spinner
}
```

Comment: Its good idea but my problem is i have a navigation drawer that extends AppCompactActivity and have toolbar also the frame layout in it. i am using this toolbar and frame layout to display all my fragments. So MainFragment which is used to display tabs extends fragment only, don't have toolbar to create custom layout for spinner